# Grabbing text and adding it to link

Tags: html

Is there a way to grab text from input area and put it to the end of "href" link and to "download=''" area? I added example below:

**Code:**

```
<input id="username" type="text" value="">

<a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://mypage.com/test/(textarea text here)" download="(textarea text here).png">Download Image</a>
```

**Result when user enter text:**

```
<input id="username" type="text" value="Monster">

<a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://mypage.com/test/Monster" download="Monster.png">Download Image</a>
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Look at javascript's onkeydown and getelementbyid( ).value and combine them. Not difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a fiddle with a possible solution. might be minimized if you want to get rid of the variables declarations, but I like my code clean. https://jsfiddle.net/sctvdL0h/1/

Html

```
<input id="username" type="text" value="">

<a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" href="" download="(textarea text here).png" id="download_link">Download Image</a>
```

JS

```
var input = document.getElementById("username");
var downloadLink = document.getElementById("download_link");
var baseLink = 'http://mypage.com/test/';
var baseFormat = '.png';

var updateLink = function() {
  var currentValue = input.value;
  downloadLink.href  = baseLink + currentValue.toString();
  downloadLink.setAttribute('download', currentValue.toString() + baseFormat); 
};
input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  updateLink();
});
input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  updateLink();
});
```

In this way you can do it configurable (change url and file extension also). This is just a possible solution not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

Add id of 'mylink' to your anchor tag.

```
<a id="mylink" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://mypage.com/test/Monster" download="Monster.png">Download Image</a>
```

Then this code will set it. You will need to decide which event you want to trigger the setting of the href. onblur is a common one.

```
document.getElementById("mylink").href=document.getElementById("username").value;
```

Comment: document.getElementById("mylink").href will overwrite the whole path. so you will have `<a id="mylink" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" href="Monster">Download Image</a>`

Comment: Yup. I can see that. So the link still has to be in front of it and it should look like: mypage.com/test/Monster.png not sure how to add it in middle.

Comment: Yes sorry forgot the concat. @UXRO . You can string search to the last occurrence of '/', then from there concat document.getElementById("username").value to the existing href. Let me know if you can't get it working.

Comment: Someone else already posted solution, thank you for helping me. I will use code you shared in other part of project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript code. i give u an exemple.

```
<script>
(function ready() {
  var input = document.getElementById('username'),
      link = document.getElementById('getLink');

  link.onclick = function() {
    link.download = input.value + ".png";
    window.open('http://mypage.com/test/' + input.value,'_blank');
  }
})();
</script>




<input id="username" type="text" value="">
<a id="getLink" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" href="">Download Image</a>
```